# Will Ubuntu Touch be updated to a Lollipop base?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I've always wanted to try Ubuntu Touch but haven't been able to get myself to buy the phones yet. I've tried to port it to my Nexus 6 but I didn't get it working because it has a KitKat base and therefore can't run on any phones that can't run on KitKat. Is there some sort of ETA on when it'll work on Lollipop devices?

Answer (score 0):

Please visit the dedicated forum: [Ubuntu Phone and Tablet](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=460)
You'll find a lot of answers because ubuntu-touch is always evolving and new devices are ported every day.